# How can I convert a cordless trimmer to a corded trimmer?

Tags: short-circuit, voltage-source

I have a cordless hair trimmer that I would like to turn into a corded unit.

Its AC/DC charging adapter outputs 3V at 1000mA, while the trimmer's original battery is a 2.4V 600mAh NiCd AA unit.

Can I just short the battery terminals and plug the trimmer into its charger for use?
[image]

Note: I tried finding the unit's manual online, but my trimmer is a cheap old model that Conair doesn't have any resources for online.

Comment: The battery may put way more current through the trimmer than the charger puts into the battery, so before you do anything else it would be a good idea to measure the current out of the freshly-charged battery with the trimmer cutting hair, then post what you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Short the battery terminals" doesn't sound good. You probably want to Remove the batteries, leave the terminals open circuit.

The principle is fine, but the real question is whether the charger will be able to power the clipper alone.  Does it (when new) take longer to charge than to discharge?  Quite likely, if it's a cheap Ni-Cd battery device, it won't have any fast charge circuits in it. Ni-Cad batteries produce a lot of current, ideal for small motors, but they usually charge slowly in cheap devices.

If it takes say 12 hours to charge, and runs down in 2 hours of use, then the charger will definitely not be able to power it.

If the batteries are still working, cut one wire and measure the current to the motor, when it's working normally. This is what your wall power supply needs to produce.

Also, the wires you use between power supply and clipper will be a problem. If it only runs on 2.4 V, a half-volt drop will affect it a lot. Do your sums carefully, and perhaps increase the supply voltage slightly.

Finally, there could be a safety issue, so be careful. Being battery powered, not plugged in, makes it safer if it's used anywhere wet. You shouldn't adapt it to be mains powered, and then use it in the bathroom, unless your DC power supply is safe for use in the bathroom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess of how the PCB is layout, just from looking at your picture:

Concentrate on the 4 contacts that is part of the switch -
Far right contact -- goes to battery+  (most obvious)
Top left contact -- goes to charger+ through a resistor or some current limit circuit
Bottom left contact -- goes to charger+ through a diode
Bottom middle contact -- goes to motor+ (least obvious, by process of elimination)

When the switch is at top, charge+ connects to battery+ with current limit to charge battery.
When the switch is at bottom, motor+ connects to battery+ and charger+ to run the motor.

So if this guess is correct, simply disconnect the battery and see if charger+ through the diode can supply enough power to run the motor. Obviously, recognize that when experimenting, things can go wrong.